# Probability distribution- standard normal dist.

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with standard normal distributions. The probability of $X<-1$ is some p which lies in the open interval (0,1). what is the probability of the event: $X^2 > 1$ and $Y^3 > 1$.

I have started with $P(X<-1)= P(X>1) = p$ (i think its right)
But now stuck at how to proceed from here... I'm thinking of using cdf but not able to fit it in?

Comment: Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P((X^2 > 1) \cap Y^3 > 1)$$
$$=P(X^2 > 1)\times P(Y > 1)$$
$$=P(X > 1)\times P(Y>1) + P(X < -1)\times P(Y>1)$$

$$=(1-\Phi(1))(1-\Phi(1)) + \Phi(-1)\times (1-\Phi(1))$$

where $\Phi(.)$ denotes the CDF of $N(0,1)$

Comment: Can you explain a little more using p?

Comment: In your Q, $p=\Phi(-1) = 1-\Phi(1)$.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help.